# System Calls to block incoming calls in iphone 4

Tags: iphone, callblocking

Is there a way to block/filter the incoming calls in iphone 4.0+

I've found a lot of apps saying that they are for blocking the calls with a price in app store.  But the reviews are negative.  Is is really possible to block calls ? Can anyone advise me on this ?

Thanks a zillion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Answer is NO** With current SDK support you can not intercept/block calls sms.

Comment: Thanks for throwing light on this Jennis :)